# Laptop Screen Issue: Weird Pixel columns and blackout of every alternate pixel row

Tags: laptop, display, graphics-card, pixels

I was using my laptop for straight many hours with the power plugged in and I was also on Google meet.
**My laptop suddenly had weird pixel lines showing up on the screen**(Check photos).

1. Weird pixel lines 1:
   [image]
2. Weird pixel lines 2:
   [image]
3. Weird pixel lines 3:
   [image]

Restarting did not help. Later when I turned it on after 7hrs, the problem persisted. I plugged it into a desktop monitor with an HDMI cable, the desktop monitor works perfectly fine. Is it a solvable issue? Can someone explain the problem here?

Also, these pixel lines are dynamic. If I hover my mouse on it, it'll change. Also as far as I can see, every alternate pixel row has turned black (example: The '-' icon of 'minimize' any window is not visible)

Answer (score 0):

Lines and shadows like that on an LCD laptop panel is a sure sign that the screen is on it's way out. If you have a local computer shop enquire how much a replacement screen would cost. Most HP laptops screens are not difficult to replace.